# Rename files in multiple directories (recursive) to the name of the directory (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I am trying to figure out how to rename files in my dir structure (movies) and to unify the names there ...

Is there any way how to achieve the following scenario?

example:

```
\tmp\test\my folder\v.txt
\tmp\test\my folder\w.pdf

\tmp\test\test folder\my subfolder\x.jpg
\tmp\test\test folder\my subfolder\y.log

\tmp\test\new folder\my path\tester\z.png
```

expected result:

```
\tmp\test\my folder\my folder.txt
\tmp\test\my folder\my folder.pdf

\tmp\test\test folder\my subfolder\my subfolder.jpg
\tmp\test\test folder\my subfolder\my subfolder.log

\tmp\test\new folder\my path\tester\tester.png
```

I was trying something but this is too much for a rookie like me :)

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

A basic solution would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

#list the files
files=$(find . -type f)

#go through each file
while read -r file
do
  #get folder path
  folderPath=$(cd "$(dirname "$file")" && pwd)

  #get file subfolder name
  subfolder=${folderPath##*/}

  #get file extension
  extension=${file##*.}

  #rename the file from old name to new name
  mv "${file}" "${folderPath}/${subfolder}.${extension}"
done <<< "$files"
```

Comment: This will break if files contain spaces.

Comment: I tested it before posting, including files and folders with spaces. Worked fine here. What makes you think it would break?

Comment: @ghoti Hm, I don't think it will break for spaces. For newlines though, it will.